# phonegap iOS build rejected due to permission issues

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Recently, my iOS build was rejected due to following issues:

**This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.**

I googled it and came to know that with iOS 10 we need to add extra plugins for media permissions and for that I have added two plugins

> cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions
>
> cordova-plugin-ios-ble-permissions

but I am unable to find the plugin for microphone permission.
any help how can I handle microphone permission for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can create plugin for setting these permission and utilise in your app. Someone has already created one for privacy description for using Camera and photo library. You can get it from [here](https://github.com/Cordobo/cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions)

You can modify same plugin for adding BLE permission.  Key for bluetooth uses is `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`  (Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description)

Answer (score 0):

Add below keys in your iOS projects's info.plist. Hope this will help...!!

[image]

Comment: thankyou for your answer but my app is based on phonegap and i have to include plugin in config.xml

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the possible ways to insert permissions in info.plist but i got the same and same message from iTunes.
Now today i got the new plugin which is updated yesterday only

> cordova-plugin-ios-microphone-permissions

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ios-microphone-permissions